# Press Power button Twice to send SMS

Tags: android, keyevent, background-service

I have written an app in which the user can send messages whenever they press a button given in the activity, and it works fine for me, but now my target is to send SMS by **using double press on power button**.

but I don't have any idea, how to do that ?

```
   Send SMS by using double press on power button
```

below is the code, which I am using to send SMS:

```
 btnPanic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String message = "My current location is:" + "\t" + currentLocation ;

            String phoneNo = editContacts.getText().toString();

            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
            while (st.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
                if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && message.trim().length()>0) {
                    sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, message);
            }
            else 
            {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448564/twice-power-button-press-sends-sms

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen that's not the solution

Comment: i'm not a fan of using the power button for an event when writing a mobile app. You won't see that either at computers ...

Comment: No, but it is a duplicate. However this should be a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android - KarelG is however right. This is unexpected behaviour for an app and certainly not recommended.

Comment: but moon requires @KarelG

Comment: you can't say this duplicate, because that question asked by other person and does not contain solution as well @AlexvandenHoogen i think you should understand this for you

Comment: i was researching and it seems possible. I [found this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365166/2412895), but you have to work it out further to detect a twice press.

Comment: @KarelG already checked that but not helpful

Answer (score 4):

I can give you Idea about how can you implement this well it's *hardcoded*.

*Pardon me if I went wrong.!!*

This is kind of conversion of key event to double click.

So here **I am considering key pressed twice as Double click**

First see key event of power button.

**1**

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER == event.getKeyCode()){
      if(time interval is less)//Consider as double click
       //code to send messages
        else            //Consider as single click
       //nothing to do   
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**2.**
You should use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to find time of two clicks in which Double click can be validated.

Try Doubleclick and record time and do it many times as you will get precise time.

**So in short you have to first find how much maximum time allowed beetween two click which is considered as doubleClick.**

So that we can differentiate beetween click and doubleclick.

**3**
So at key event you need to do this

```
long l=0;//at start not in key event handler

if(l=0){l=System.currentTimeMillis();}//clicked first time
else{l=System.currentTimeMillis()-l;}//second time
```

And you are done **use this long values to decide is it click or double click**.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // do what you want with the power button

        String message = "My current location is:" + "\t" + currentLocation ;

        String phoneNo = editContacts.getText().toString();

        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(phoneNo,",");
        while (st.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String tempMobileNumber = (String)st.nextElement();
            if(tempMobileNumber.length()>0 && message.trim().length()>0) {
                sendSMS(tempMobileNumber, message);
        }
        else 
        {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for
http://www.nkonecny.com/blog/2012/02/16/capture-power-button-keypress/

same thing you can check twice since you want the power button to be pressed twice so I think it will serve your purpose.